# Rider: enable file-scoped namespaces

Tags: c#, .net-core, namespaces, rider

I'm struggling to get File-scoped namespaces enabled in Rider. As a result I get a `Namespace body block expected` error in Rider when having something like:

```
namespace SomeProject.Interfaces; (error 'Namespace body block expected' here)

public interface IInterfaceA
{
    
}
```

I tried to find `Namespaces` in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > C# > Syntax Style` to try and switch the scope of namespaces.

But I can't see the option although that is what is recommended in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/File_Scoped_Namespaces.html#preferences.

[image: settings]

Is there a way to get to display this option? OR is there another way to change the namespace scope?

Rider version:

```
JetBrains Rider 2021.2.3
Build #RD-212.5712.52, built on December 24, 2021
```

Also I'm using C#10. DotNet Core 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `Namespaces` option to come just by updating to the latest version.

Version details:

```
JetBrains Rider 2022.1.2
Build #RD-221.5787.36, built on June 2, 2022
```